# Splitting a sum to find a closed form of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{n-1}x^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find a closed form for
>   $$S = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n}{n-1}x^{n-1}$$

**My solution**
The radius of convergence is $R=1$ and the series does not converge in $\pm 1$. Rewrite the sum as
$$\begin{align}S &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+2}{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)x^{n+1}=\\
&\color{red}{=}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1} \color{red}{+} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}=\\
&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^x t^n\mathrm dt=\\
&=\frac{x}{1-x} - \ln(1-x)\qquad \forall x \in (-1, 1)
\end{align}$$

My question is, is it correct to split the sum like that? Are there conditions on that step? Usually, in exercises involving sums I do the opposite, and I know that the radius of convergence of the new sum is $R = \min\{R_1, R_2\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is one of the arithmetic rules for series (and sequences). If the summands converge, then also the term-wise sum. If the sum and one of the summands converge, then also the other as the difference of the former.

---

PS: The computation looks good. I would have shifted the sum only by index-difference 1.

Comment: Thanks. I shifted by two because I memorized McLaurin expansions from $n=0$.